# Is AttributeError working as it should pandas df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, attributeerror

Trying to add a number (type float) from one of two columns in a pd dataframe using the following code:

```
"""
creating dict of {symbol:[spot, aggregate]
"""

abn_dict = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])

for (col, row) in abn_df.iterrows():
    try:
        row.loc["Quantity Long"].isnull()
        abn_dict[row.loc["Symbol"]][1] += row.loc["Quantity Short"]
    except AttributeError:
        abn_dict[row.loc["Symbol"]][1] += row.loc["Quantity Long"]
```

If the quantity long column is NaN, it should add the quantity short to the second element in the abn_dict values.

This is however not working with the above code and wanted to ask why.

Comment: What do you expect to raise an `AttributeError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, you have no condition in your code. Also, as per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), `pandas.DataFrame.iterrows()` returns (index, row), note (col, row).

Try refactoring like this:

```py
for _, row in abn_df.iterrows():
    if row.loc["Quantity Long"]:
        abn_dict[row.loc["Symbol"]][1] += row.loc["Quantity Short"]
    else:
        abn_dict[row.loc["Symbol"]][1] += row.loc["Quantity Long"]
```

Comment: Cheers, got it working after I woke up this morning. Quite new to python so don't always understand how to call things (like the isnull). Eventually got conditions working with `var = pd.isnull(row.loc["Quantity Long"])` and then using `if not var:`.